# Cropping text in iOS in CodenameOne

Tags: fonts, look-and-feel, codenameone

In some places in my app in Label-s and TextArea-s font cropping on top side of Component. I have come across such thing only in iOS. And still the font in Simulator with iOS theme is not cut off.

An example:
[image]

Must be: [image]

Comment: Is this with a custom font? How was that font created/installed?

Comment: Yes. This is loaded ttf font

Comment: Does it happen with the builtin font?

Comment: No. But I can't use builtin fonts in this situation.

Comment: I suggest filing an issue with a test case we can reproduce.